# How to use sprintf to show string "\t"?

Tags: r, string-formatting

I have an algorithm to identify the separator used in in a .txt file. I want to output the separator found using `cat()`. I am using `%s` with `sprintf()` to  no avail.

```
current.sep = "\t"

cat(sprintf("Found separator : %s. \n", current.sep))
## Found separator :    .

cat(sprintf("Found separator : %s. \n", "current.sep"))
## Found separator : current.sep. 

## I want:
## Found separator : \t.
```

Comment: It... is showing it? `## Found separator :    .` (comment removed the spaces but w/e) has a `\t` in it, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_separator <- function(separator) {

    expr <- deparse(paste0("Found separator : ", separator, "."))
    cat(substr(expr, 2, nchar(expr) - 1))

}

print_separator(current.sep)
## Found separator : \t.
```